# storing max value into a variable from a query using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, postgresql

I have a problem of retrieving a max value from psql query to store it into a variable. I am using VBA.

Anyone knows how to do it?

```
mobjCmd.CommandText = "SELECT max(id) as max_ID from tbl_maps;"
Set mobjRst = mobjCmd.Execute
    maxID = mobjRst.Fields("max_ID") 'this part, variable should get max_ID
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you get any error? What is the problem with the above statement?.

Comment: I cannot remember the error shown. But I had found already the error on it.. It simply the syntax of retrieving the max_ID.
Here it is:

`mobjCmd.CommandText = "SELECT max(id) as max_ID from tbl_butuanmaps;

    Set mobjRst = mobjCmd.Execute
        maxID = mobjRst!max_ID`

Anyways thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT max(id) as max_ID` will report result in

> "max_id"

column, not

> "max_ID"

... try changing `mobjRst.Fields("max_ID")` to `mobjRst.Fields("max_id")`

and visa versa if you want to have max_ID column you should `SELECT max(id) as "max_ID"`

Answer (score 0):

I had found the error.

Here is the correct syntax:

> `maxID = mobjRst!max_ID`

.I was just messed up on retrieving the max_ID. Thanks anyways.